# Role of new keyword in Java

Tags: java

I am not sure how `new` keyword behaves in Java. Is it for sure that every time I will use `new` keyword, a new Object will be created on heap?

I got this doubt when I was studying following example-

```
class Mixer {
  Mixer() { }
  Mixer(Mixer m) { m1 = m; }
  Mixer m1;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mixer m2 = new Mixer();
    Mixer m3 = new Mixer(m2); // Does it create any new mixer object?
    m3.go();
    Mixer m4 = m3.m1;          m4.go(); 
    Mixer m5 = m2.m1;          m5.go();
  }
  void go() { System.out.print("hi "); }
}
```

The line `Mixer m3 = new Mixer(m2);` invokes a constructor which does not create any new object. So, is it that no new object was created?

Also, Which variable refers to which object in the end of program, i.e. till we get `NullPointerExcetion` for variable `m5`.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't create a new object?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: @DaveNewton- If the new object is created then which variable is referring to that one?

Comment: @PrateekSingla The one you assign the result to -- `m3` in this case.

Comment: @PrateekSingla `m3`--what else could it be?

Comment: I got confused between constructor and method, I thought it is not returning anything, so `m3` might be a null reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new always creates a new instance (so always reserves heap memory, etc.).

This should illustrate it. note that == on an instance will tell you if it is the same instance (object) or a different one. (which is why you should always use equals, unless this is what you want to do)

I've added a funny thing happening with strings. "abc" does not create a new instance, but reuses an existing one. but when you call new on the String class it does.

```
public class Test {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Test() {
        value = "default";
    }
    public Test(Test t) {
        this.value = t.getValue();
    }

    public Test(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        Test t2 = new Test(t1);

        if (t1 == t2) {
            System.out.println("t1 == t2. should not happen");
        } else {
            System.out.println("t1 is a different instance from t2");
        }

        String s1 = "test";
        String s2 = "test";

        if (s1 == s2) {
            System.out.println("s1 == s2. strings initialized with quotes don't always get a new instance.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("s1 is a different instance from s2. should not happen");
        }

        String s3 = new String("test");
        String s4 = new String(s3);

        if (s3 == s4) {
            System.out.println("s3 == s4. should not happen.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("s3 is a different instance from s4, as they were newed.");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes - every time you use `new` (as a keyword) a new object will be created. In this case:

```
Mixer m3 = new Mixer(m2);
```

> The line Mixer m3 = new Mixer(m2); invokes a constructor which does not create any new object.

Your reasoning is completely incorrect. A new `Mixer` is being created using `m2` as a parameter. Usually this indicates a copy constructor - creating a new Mixer with the same properties as the old one (but it is always a new, distinct object, and doesn't technically *have* to copy the properties of the object passed in at all.)

Comment: And m5 causes a NPE because it *is* null. (Set to m2.m1 which is null)

Comment: But m2 is just reference variable to the "old" mixer object, and that is being passed in Mixer construct. This is actually creating a new reference variable for "old" mixer object, isn't it?

Comment: `m2` isn't null - but `m2` is created without a parameter, so its `m1` field is null (and this is what causes the NPE, `m2.m1`)

Comment: Not germane to the question, but..., though it has the form of a copy constructor, it is not implemented that way. Instead of copying from one object to the new one, the old object is set to a class variable, creating a parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 1):

From the programmer's perspective, `new` causes the creation of a new object.

However, the compiler may perform [escape analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis) to determine whether the object really needs to be created on the heap at runtime.

For your last question, your code creates two objects. One is referenced by m2, m3.m1 and m4, and the other is referenced by m3.

Answer (score 1):

First, forget about the stack/heap distinction - that is an implementation detail of the compiler or the runtime (depending on the language in question). It might make a difference if you are doing systems programming in C or assembly, but not when you are working in garbage-collected languages and environments like Java or .NET.

And to answer your question: `new` actually does two things in most(?) (all?) languages that has such an operator. It first allocates memory somewhere to hold an instance of the type, and then calls a constructor to initialize an instance of the type in that newly allocated memory. Constructor chaining then may cause other constructors to be called (either on the same type, base classes/superclasses of the type, or anything that type's constructor needs to do its work).

As pointed out by [@berry120](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942298/486504), a constructor taking a parameter of the same type as the type that the constructor is for *usually indicates* a copy constructor. Another way of achieving the same result is to have and make an explicit call to something like a `clone()` method which returns a copy of the object it is called on.

Answer (score 0):

It does create a new object, and its constructor gets passed a reference to another object `m2` that you have already created.